# Sharing the common CSS rules of CK Editor for correct displaying of the formatted text outside the CKEditor

Tags: css, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Suppose we added the image in CKEdtitor and aligned it to right:

[image]

CKEditor will add `image` and `image-style-align-right` classes to `figure` element:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum of something like this&nbsp;</p>
<figure class="image image-style-align-right">
    <img src="https://XXXXX.com/116cc956-4cf4-4d2a-98cf-ffa69ab0eb3c.jpeg">
</figure>
```

Now we want the inputted HTML will be submitted by email? Above HTML must be submitted to the backend, then all styles must be converted to inline CSS. But how the backend will know about `.image`, `.image-style-align-right` and similar CSS rules?

There are below styles in `theme/imagestyle.css` file of [@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image) package:

```css
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2003-2020, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

:root {
    --ck-image-style-spacing: 1.5em;
}

.ck-content {
    & .image-style-side {
        float: right;
        margin-left: var(--ck-image-style-spacing);
        max-width: 50%;
    }

    & .image-style-align-left {
        float: left;
        margin-right: var(--ck-image-style-spacing);
    }

    & .image-style-align-center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    & .image-style-align-right {
        float: right;
        margin-left: var(--ck-image-style-spacing);
    }
}
```

### Problem 1: The source styles are in frontend and written by PostCSS

First, above code is PostCSS. Because I must not migrate to PostCSS just because using the CKEditor, I can not include this file to my source code written by other CSS preprocessor. In frontend, [the Webpack compiles these styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#webpack-configuration) an apply it dynamically when application starts (I mean, no file with compiled CSS available):

[image]

But how to bring up these styles to server?

### Problem 2: How to bring up to server only these CSS classes which will be used and no more?

Well, even if I convert above `.image-style-side` , `.image-style-align-center` etc. to CSS and submit them to server, I will be enough only for Image feature. But the other CKEdtitor plugins adds other CCS classes and these classes are in numerous of other files!

Сonversely, there are a lot of CKEditor classes in which we are don't need on backend, e. g. `ck-editor__editable`, `ck-rounded-corners`, `ck-editor__editable_inline`: there classes are for CKEditor's GUI and will not require once editing will done?

### Problem 3: The CSS variables

Above listing includes the CSS variables like `--ck-image-style-spacing`, `--ck-image-style-spacing` etc. To make inline CSS, server must know about them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, there are several major time consuming problems to be solved with approach that you took.
Key to a successful email template is compatibility with many different email clients.
Email clients support archaic HTML tags, such as `<table>` for creating layout. Inline styles are also preferred. Many modern CSS properties are not supported at all. For example, border radius is not compatible in some clients, so rounded buttons will actually be button images instead of code. Different fonts are also not rendered.

If I were you (and if CKEditor doesn't have email templating), I'd post the template you created to some of the freelancer platforms out there and say 'guys, how much to convert this HTML to email compatible HTML'. That's the fastest and cheapest way. Test resulting code by sending it in email and checking it out in different email clients.

Other way is for you to get to know what creating HTML and styling for emails is all about. Good starting point is to analyze (and perhaps reuse) HTML from HTML emails that you received from, let's say, your local cell service provider.
You'll need to do a research on the topic to find out what suits your needs, but here are some basic guidelines:

- [supported HTML tags in emails](https://medium.com/@ranadeepbhuyan/supported-html-tags-in-common-email-clients-2cc11e1ae283)
- [step-by-step guide to creating email templates](https://email.uplers.com/blog/step-step-guide-create-html-email/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! First, thank you for the references. "post the template you created to some of the freelancer platforms" - It's impossible to ask for converting of each email. Well, let's make the verdict. "No such functionality in CKEditor, you need to write the substitutes of CKEdtior styles for your emails yourself", isn't it?

Comment: 1) Freelancer should only create a single valid email template, so you wouldn't have to.
2) Yes, unfortunately, it seems that CKEditor generated HTML can only serve as an example, if you decide to outsource the work on email template.

Comment: O'K! I accepted your answer and gave you the reputation prize.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it, although I just wanted to give you pointers, since solution to your question is very complex to be explained in brief